# Как связать Jtree и JTexArea?

Tags: java, swing

У меня 2 класса MyTextArea и MyTree:

```
public class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {
       public MyTextArea() {
        setColumns(10);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        setEditable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
}
public void setTextField(String s ){
        setText(s);
    }
}
public class MyTree extends JTree {
    private MyTextArea tf;
    public Tree() {
            setRootVisible(true);
        setEditable(true);
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 400));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250, 400));
          addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   DefaultMutableTreeNode Mnode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)getLastSelectedPathComponent();
              if ( Mnode!=null){
              Object nodeInfo = Mnode.getUserObject();
              String s = nodeInfo.toString();
              tf.setTextField(s);
            }
            }
        });
}
```

Не пойму как правильно передать значение, чтоб оно отображалось в MyTextArea...?

Comment: Вот меня удивляет, как можно выкладывать такой код и говорить что-то не понимаешь, тут конструктор неправильный - это первая ошибка и код уже не будет компилится, сформулируй задание попроще - помогу разобратся, но тут неплохо было бы обьект MyTextArea создать для начала.

Comment: где конструктор не правильный?) код компилится) я просто не стал тут в MyTree выкладывать описание модели..
формулирую проще: Нужно чтоб в MyTextArea отображалось название выбранного node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понимаю, код корявый, но как-то так должно работать и у вас

```
public class jTreeTest extends JTree {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode child = 
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode(this.getSelectionModel());
    static JTextField field;

    public jTreeTest() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                field.setText(child.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        field = new JTextField();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        jTreeTest tree = new jTreeTest();
                  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.add(tree);
          frame.add(field, new BorderLayout().PAGE_END);
              frame.setSize(400,500);
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```